# cgcontextaddcurvetopoint is unavailable in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

Can you please help me to resolve this issue as I am not getting any idea to resolve it.

```
for (x,height) in variances.enumerated()
    {
        let p = CGPoint(x: step + waveWidth*CGFloat(x), y: self.frame.size.height/2)
        let cp1 = CGPoint(x: p.x - (3.0/4.0)*waveWidth ,y: p.y + (waveHeight + CGFloat(variance/2) - height))
        let cp2 = CGPoint(x: p.x - (1.0/4.0)*waveWidth, y: p.y - (waveHeight + CGFloat(variance/2) - height))

        CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, p.x, p.y)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [swift-evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md) and [Xcode 8 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html).

Summary: In Swift 3 C-function declarations from Frameworks like CoreGraphics are not imported as `CGContextDoSomething: CGContext -> T -> U` but like member methods of type CGContext. So it must be called like:

```
let context: CGContext = <…> // Get CGContext instance, how is irrelevant for example
context.doSomething(<…>)
```

Also you should try adding CGPath with curve instead of directly drawing in context.